# Label does not have time to upgrade, depending on the text

Tags: xcode, swift, label, height, width

Label doesn't have time to upgrade, depending on the text. When entering text in the label and the subsequent entry of the width and height of the label in a variable, it records the value of the value of the old label. How can I solve the problem?

```
labelHidden.text = "Some text ..."
textWidth = labelHidden.bounds.width
textHeight = labelHidden.bounds.height
```

Comment: Please provide more detailed question

Comment: Perhaps resizing occurs when the Label is rendered, ie in the next frame.

Comment: How do I make a frame delay?

Comment: Try setting the textWidth and textHeight from the frame of labelHidden instead of bounds. Also can try set the values to nil after settings the label text